# NodeJs live edit excel file

Tags: node.js, excel, live

So I have an excel file that is open.
I am using Node.js to make changes to the file.

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
async function excelOp() {
    let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook = await workbook.xlsx.readFile('exceledit.xlsx'); // replace question_39869739.xls with your file
    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1'); // replace sheetname with actual sheet name
    worksheet.getRow('1').getCell('A').value = 450; // replace rowNumber and cellNumber with the row and cell you want to modify
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('exceledit.xlsx');
}

excelOp();
```

But to see the changes in the excel file, I've to close it and re-open it. How can I see the changes made like in Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need interval refreshing for Excel. From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/refresh-an-external-data-connection-in-excel-1524175f-777a-48fc-8fc7-c8514b984440

1. Click a cell in the external data range.
2. On the Data tab, in the Queries & Connections group, click the arrow under Refresh All, and then click Connection Properties.
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNFSX.png)
3. Click the Usage tab.
4. Select the Refresh every check box, and then enter the number of minutes between each refresh operation.